# Navigate from UITabViewController to UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an application where I want to Navigate from UITabViewController to UITableViewController on click of a button.

Can somebody tell me how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Use following method, pass the name of method to your button’s target.
And, Just paste the name of your TableViewController when you want navigate from first..

```
-(IBAction) clickButton : (id) sender
{
   ViewOfSecondTableViewController *nextTable = [[ViewOfSecondTableViewController alloc] 
              initWithNibName:@"ViewOfSecondTableViewController" 
              bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
   [self.navigationController nextTable animated:YES];
 }
```

Comment: I have done this. However it is not navigating but NSLog shows the method is being called

Comment: Add different values in both tables & Add breakpoint on 2nd controller.. check it out.

Comment: I have one table and one tab view controller